# IIS 8 on Windows Server 2012 giving weird errors

Tags: c#, iis, iis-8

I am moving some of my code from azure to my local server but it is giving me wierd errors when browsing the site.

```
Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Could not create type 'dtu._02267.LameDuck.LameDuckService'.

Source Error: 


Line 1:  <%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="LameDuckService.asmx.cs" Class="dtu._02267.LameDuck.LameDuckService" %>
```

http://dtu.02267.sogaard.us/LameDuck/LameDuckService.asmx

The default.aspx file is also giving errors
http://dtu.02267.sogaard.us/LameDuck/

it is the same code as hosted on azure, and it is workign fine there:
http://sogaardlameduck.azurewebsites.net/LameDuckService.asmx
http://sogaardlameduck.azurewebsites.net/

The wierd thing is the my local iss server is also hosting a MVC site and it is working fine:
http://redcloud.sogaard.us/

Update:
[image]
[image]

Comment: The bin folder is present? With the assemblies in it? It is running as site or is it just a folder?

Comment: It seems to be unable to find the assembly `dtu_02267.LameDuck`, or whatever the assembly is called that contains `dtu._02267.LameDuck.LameDuckService` ensure that it's in the `/bin` folder of your service.

Comment: Application pool's framework version? How is looking the IIS feature set installation?

Comment: 4.0, but it have 4.5 installed! The MVC website is running ASP.NET MVC 5